# currency in the millions as an adjective

Tags: adjectives, money

Would it be:

1) It was a $24-million project.

or

2) It was a $24 million project.

I'm thinking (2), although if I were to write it out as words, I would write "a 24-million-dollar project." But in the "currency symbol" "numeral" format, it's not like "$24" (twenty-four dollars) is modifying "million".

Anyway, any advice/wisdom would be appreciated.

Comment: If you were to write it out in words, you would write *twenty-four-million-dollar project*.

Comment: @JasonBassford why is that? "twenty four million dollar project" can hardly be interpreted any other way (than that intended.) The hyphens would be entirely redundant (ergo they should not be used.)

Comment: @GiuPiete My point was that *24* is not written in words, it's written in numerals. Also, hyphenation is a matter of style and far from redundant in many cases. Every style guide I know of says to write *twenty-four*, for example. The number is never expressed in words as *twenty four*, without a hyphen. And the rest follows from there.

Comment: @JasonBassford ja, didn't mean to imply that hypenation is always redundant, just redundant when it's redundant (when the meaning is clear without it,) aiding clarity after all is the purpose of punctuation as grammatical tools. But w/e, if them's the rules..